# OpenMp with custom reduction for GMP addition

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp, gmp

I have

```
mpf_t omp_mpf_add(mpf_t out, mpf_t in) {
  mpf_add(out, out, in);
  return out;
}
```

And i want to make this function as an openmp reduction

```
# pragma omp declare reduction (mpf_add:mpf_t:omp_mpf_add(omp_out,omp_in)) \
    initializer(omp_priv=omp_orig)
```

But i get `error: reduction type cannot be an array type` error.

what should i change so that the function will work and i can use it with

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(mpf_add:x)
```

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: @tambre I dont mind wether the fix will utilize c++ feature. If posible i prefer c, but if it is not, then i'm okay with c++. As i dont know if such feature is posible in c code. my knowledge is not deep enough :).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Compiler version might also be relevant.

Comment: You don't return a mpf_t, look at any existing GMP function for comparison. I don't know what types are valid for openmp reductions, did you try mpf_class, where addition is just + ?